# AWS Elastic Beanstalk difference between env.yml VS .config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm making some tests with the AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform for the first time to discover it.
But i'm facing an issue :

The documentation show us that we can describe the environment configuration inside a ".ebextensions/myConf.config" file.

But i also discover that we can describe the environment configuration inside a "env.yml" in the root project (including more options like "Platform").

The question is, what is the difference between the two files ? Should i use both ? In which case ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I was wondering about this myself. The EB documentation is a real nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two settings choices are complementary, although there is some overlap between [env.yaml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-manifest.html) and [.ebextentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).

For example, things like `CName`, `EnvironmentName` or `SolutionStack` can only be set in `env.yaml`. So instead of setting up their values in EB console or CLI, you could define them in `env.yaml` to ensure reproducible deployments of your EB. Thus, `env.yaml` can be considered are more **specific to EB environment** itself, not to your application.

In contrast, `.ebextentions` contains configuration scripts that are more coupled with **details of your application**. What commands should your run to bootstrap it, what config files should you setup or modify it.

> Should i use both ? In which case ?

Generally I see `.ebextentions` used much more often than `env.yaml`. Thus, to begin your EB journey I would recommend just focusing on `.ebextentions`.

There are **many more possibilities** of setting up EB than only `.ebextentions` or `env.yaml`. There are also `.platform`, deployment hooks, `Buildfile`, `Procfile`, saved configurations and probably some other things I can't remember.